# Angularjs checkbox filter on two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filter

I've been struggling to filter two different arrays, one with the checkbox values and another with whole data. In other terms, first array contains the field values from a sharepoint list and the second array contains the items from same sharepoint list. How can I filter based on the checkbox selected. Here is my code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in processes">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filteredData"/>{{x}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat = "y in toBeFiltered | filter: {filteredData : true}">
<span class="title">{{y.Title}}</span>
<span class="process"> {{y.process}}</span>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.processes = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ];
  $scope.toBeFiltered = [{
  "Title": "title1",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste"]
  }, {"Title" : "title2",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste, Berglunds Snabbkop"]

  },{"Title" : "title2",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste, Berglunds Snabbkop,Ernst Handel, 
  Centro Comercial Moctezuma"]
  }];
});
</script>
```

I tried using ng-model, but that didn't work. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you need to provide value to the check box inputs which will be set in the ng-model, when the check box is checked.

Comment: ng-repeat is doing that. It is looping through the processes filter and displaying it.

Comment: I meant something like <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filteredData" value="{{x}}"/>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to keep track of selected options, so I added **checked** property to each processes object, which then ng-model change it's value.

second I changed the two arrays which were like this
**["Alfreds Futterkiste, Berglunds Snabbkop,Ernst Handel, Centro Comercial Moctezuma"]**
from one long value to
 **["Alfreds Futterkiste", "Berglunds snabbköp","Ernst Handel", "Centro comercial Moctezuma"]**

last you need to define custom filter function, in my case **containFn** which checks each **toBeFiltered** item and see if some of this item's processes is contained in **processes array** with condition that its checked == true

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.processes = [
    {name: "Alfreds Futterkiste", checked: false},
    {name: "Berglunds snabbköp", checked: false},
    {name:"Centro comercial Moctezuma", checked: false},
    {name: "Ernst Handel", checked: false}
  ];
  $scope.toBeFiltered = [{
  "Title": "title1",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste"]
  }, {"Title" : "title2",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste", "Berglunds snabbköp"]

  },{"Title" : "title2",
  "process": ["Alfreds Futterkiste", "Berglunds snabbköp","Ernst Handel", "Centro comercial Moctezuma"]
  }];
  $scope.containFn = function(item){
   var found = false;
    item.process.forEach(function(element){ 
       if($scope.processes.some(function(it) {return  (it.name == element && it.checked== true) })) found = true;
     });
     return found;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat="x in processes">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.checked"/>{{x.name}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat = "y in toBeFiltered | filter: containFn">
<span class="title">{{y.Title}}</span>
<span class="process"> {{y.process}}</span>
</div>
    
</div>
```

run the snippet, if there is something isn't clear, or I didn't get feel free to comment

Comment: Thanks Basel and sorry for putting bad array values. :P Just two additional things, first: I'm getting data from sharepoint list so let's just say I have all my values in $scope.processes = data; , how can I add changed property in this case and second, if we select a value, it brings up all the entries that the other array contains. But what I want is when we select only "Alfreds Futterkiste" then only first title should come up. And if I select multiple then based on selected checkboxes. Sorry for poor explanation, I'm a newbie. Hope you got it. Thanks!